# Postgres allows to UPDATE however only SELECT is granted

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Owner of table `x` is user `dave`.

Only `SELECT` is granted to `cloudsqlsuperuser`, however user `anton` is able to update data in table `x`. How it's possible?

```
=> \du
                                                         List of roles
         Role name         |                         Attributes                         |               Member of               
---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 anton                     | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqladmin             | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 cloudsqlagent             | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqliamserviceaccount | Cannot login                                               | {}
 cloudsqliamuser           | Cannot login                                               | {}
 cloudsqlimportexport      | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqlreplica           | Replication                                                | {pg_monitor}
 cloudsqlsuperuser         | Create role, Create DB                                     | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend}
 dave                      | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser,postgres}
```

```
=> \dt
                   List of relations
 Schema |           Name           | Type  |   Owner   
--------+--------------------------+-------+-----------
 public | x                        | table | dave
```

```
=> \z x
                                      Access privileges
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |       Access privileges       | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------+----------
 public | x            | table | dave=arwdDxt/dave            +|                   | 
        |              |       | =arwdDxt/dave                +|                   | 
        |              |       | cloudsqlsuperuser=r/dave     +|                   | 
(1 row)
```

I am able to do UPDATE as `anton` user. Shouldn't it be forbidden?

```
=> update x set ...
UPDATE 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=arwdDxt/dave` means all privileges are granted to the pseudo-role `PUBLIC`, of which `anton` is obviously a member. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) states that

> any particular role will have the sum of privileges granted directly to it, privileges granted to any role it is presently a member of, and privileges granted to `PUBLIC`. Thus, for example,[...] revoking `SELECT` from a user might not prevent that user from using `SELECT` if `PUBLIC` or another membership role still has `SELECT` rights.

Subsequently, you'll have to revoke the `PUBLIC` `UPDATE` privilege to prevent `anton` from updating the table.